# Cost (Something) In The Hundreds Of Thousands Of Dollars

Tags: ellipsis

I have a question about the usage pattern of the verb "*cost*":

> 1. The repair would *cost* ***something*** *in the hundreds of thousands of dollars*.
> 2. The repair would *cost in the hundreds of thousands of dollars*.

The first sentence is definitely standard English.  The second sentence (dropping "*something*") is not found in dictionaries, but could be found on google.  But is it standard English?

Comment: The second is just as natural-sounding to me as the first—maybe moreso (AmE native speaker).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using "WOULD" for talking about the result of an event that you imagine.

Would + verb. (you can use Could or Might, too.)

**The repair would cost hundreds of thousands of dollars.**

Comment: Yes!  In that example the rest is just noise.  A case where you'd want it: "With a cost in the hundreds of thousands of dollars, that repair isn't likely to be performed this fiscal year."

Answer (score 0):

This sentence might be helpful:

> The cost of the repair would be **somewhere** in the hundreds of thousands of dollars.

Now, I don't mean to contradict Brian, but I prefer to use *somewhere* and feel that *something* sounds a bit off.  What we are saying formally is that the cost of the equipment would be somewhere in the range of $100,000 and $1,000,000.  The meaning stays the same if we leave out the word *somewhere* (or *something*) entirely.

The underlying meaning of the usage is usually that it would cost more than we want to pay.

We might also say this:

> The cost of the repair would be **something like** several hundred thousand dollars.